# How to make Windows 7 show domain user and local user on login screen

Tags: windows-7, login

A notebook of my company is a member of our company's domain, and moreover there exists a local user account.

My colleague with this notebook is using a domain user for work and a local user for using the notebook for private purposes. Switching via "other users" is quite annoying, as the domain name is quite long and has to be typed in every time one switches to the domain user.

The notebook is joined to the domain. If the last login was local, the user has to type `domainname\username`, otherwise Windows won't find the domain user.

Is there a way to display both the domain user and the local user on the win7 welcome screen?

Comment: I don't think there is a setting like this. It's mostly for security reasons that on a domain PC you should see who was logged on that PC. Plus if you have about 20 people using this PC (in a school for example) then there would be 20 entries you would need to scroll through. I recommend you to also use .\username instead since it's much shorter depending on the PC name

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

Join the laptop to the domain.  This should then default all logins to the domain, then your colleague will have to type `computername\username` to login to his local account.

Comment: OP mentions it is part of the domain

Comment: @DaveM The way it's described, it doesn't sound like it's actually joined.  It shouldn't default to the local machine for login.

Comment: sorry for being not precise enough: the notebook is actually joined to the domain. If the last login waslocal, the user has to type domainname\username, otherwise windows won't find the domain user.

Comment: Just an FYI instead of computername\username in Win7 you can just type .\username for a local user.  You're welcome :)

Comment: Is the user using a domain account that has the same username portion as the local account? For example, "mydomain\myuseracct" and "localhost\myuseracct"? If I try to log in with "administrator" on any of my domained machines, I have to preface it with "mydomain\", otherwise the login screen assumes I mean local admin.